# MVC asp.net application published :: Error :: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I tried publishing my website in MVC asp.net on my website, but I am getting an error :

> Error :: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have
>   permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that
>   you supplied.

I have tried a number of things in my webconfig aswell.

```
<configuration> 
  <configSections> 
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --> 
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" /> 
  </configSections> 
  <appSettings> 
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" /> 
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" /> 
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> 
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> 
</appSettings> 
<system.web> 
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" /> 
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" /> 
<httpModules> 
<add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" /> 
</httpModules> 
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
  <forms loginUrl="Account/Login"></forms> 
</authentication> 
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider"> 
  <providers> 
    <clear /> 
    <add name="MyProvider" type="CampusRiver_Hospital.MyRoleProvider" /> 
  </providers> 
</roleManager> 
</system.web> 
 <runtime> 
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
  <dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /> 
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /> 
  </dependentAssembly> 
  <dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /> 
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /> 
   </dependentAssembly> 
   <dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /> 
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /> 
    </dependentAssembly> 
    </assemblyBinding> 
  </runtime> 
  <system.codedom> 
 <compilers> 
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" /> 
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" /> 
   </compilers> 
 </system.codedom> 
<system.webServer> 
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" /> 
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules> 
 <handlers> 
  <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" /> 
 </handlers> 
 </system.webServer> 
 <entityFramework> 
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> 
  <parameters> 
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" /> 
   </parameters> 
  </defaultConnectionFactory> 
 <providers> 
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" /> 
  </providers> 
  </entityFramework> 
  <connectionStrings> 

   <add name="HospitalContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.HospitalContext.csdl|res://*/Models.HospitalContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.HospitalContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=****;user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings> 
  <location path="."> 
   <system.web> 
   <authorization> 
    <allow users="?" /> 
   </authorization> 
   </system.web> 
  </location> 
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe you have wrong data source in connectionString ?

Comment: Does your app pool account running the website have access/permissions to the folder the code is located at?

Comment: everything is working on my laptop, just when i publish it, it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

The credential on which the IIS application pool is running on does not have access to the folder of the deployed application. Try giving a valid credential there, that have proper access permissions.

**Go to**

*Application Pool -> select your pool->Advanced Setting->Process Model->Identity*

And set a valid Identity here.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But I dont have IIS 7 installed on my laptop. I published the website on arvixe.com. Trying to run the website from the domain link, but I am getting an error. akshigakhar/CampusRiver..How can I make changes there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I contacted admin and got a user name and password set up. and it worked.